# what type of event when add atribute scope session into modelmap?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to catch event add attribute `"fullName"` scope session, i try to use `ApplicationListener` it didn't work.

Here my cotroller

```
@SessionAttributes({ "fullName" })
public class LoginController {
@RequestMapping(value = "home", method = RequestMethod.POST)
ModelAndView loginPost(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute User user, HttpSession session) {
    String fullName = loginService.getUserFullName(user);
    if (fullName == null) {
        model.addAttribute("error", "Username or password is invalid");
        return new ModelAndView("login");
    } else {
        model.addAttribute("fullName", fullName);
        return new ModelAndView("home", model);
    }
}
```

and listener

```
public class Listener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEvent> {
    private static int countUserOnline;

    public static int getCountUserOnline() {
        return countUserOnline;
    }
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        if (event instanceof HttpSessionDestroyedEvent) {
            countUserOnline--;
        }
        else if(event instanceof HttpSessionDestroyedEvent) {
            countUserOnline++;
        } 
    }
}
```